# permissions in \AppData\Local\Temp dir do not apply

Tags: windows

We've been struggerling with some files which seem to be dissapearing in a sub-directory of user specific %TMP% directories.

After some searching in the logs, i found that the application that uses the files deletes it through the user's account.

Because the files need to stay put, we've tried to allow only Read & Execute rights to all users on the system but the files still get deleted. Only when we remove ownership entireley as well as block all permissions on the folder and subdirectories, the files cannot be deleted anymore. However, the application needs read & execute rights in order to function properly.

Is this standard behaviour of the %temp% directory, or is this some kind of policy that's overlooked?

Fixing the permissions wil allow us to use the application again while the developer sorts out the issue.

Kind thanks!

Removing all permisions of all users on the sytstem > Files cannot be deleted but application crashes
Blocking all permisions of all users on the system except Read & execute > Files can be deleted

We're hoping that the files' contents can be read & executed but not be deleted.